# How to separate arrays in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have stored three arrays inside another array. Now I need to separate those three arrays and store in three different arrays. How to do this?

```
Nsmutablearray *arr=[[nsmutablearray alloc]initwithobjects:arr1,arr2,arr3];
```

now i need to divide it to following model

```
Nsmutablearray *firstarr=arr1;

Nsmutablearray *secondarr=arr2;

Nsmutablearray *thirdarr=arr3;
```

I need to do this in for in loop.

Comment: It's an array!!  Index it!!

Comment: @yashwanth Why are you requesting a "for in loop"?

Comment: -1, You didn't even bother write the type names correctly! When you put no effort into your question, are you really expecting us to put any effort into answering it?

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you're looking for?

```
NSMutableArray *firstArray = arr[0];
NSMutableArray *secondArray = arr[1];
NSMutableArray *thirdArray = arr[2];
```

Note that the `NSArray` class uses the Objective-C subscripting syntax as shorthand for `[arr objectAtIndex:0]` (these are equivalent, but it's shorter and clearer to write it as an array subscript).

Answer (score 0):

Use it with array index you can separate all array..

```
 // Array at Index 0
 NSArray *firstarr=arr[0];
 // Array at Index 1
 NSArray *secondarr=arr[1];
 // Array at Index 2
 NSArray *thirdarr=arr3[2];
```